# Vertical-align image from CSS with varying p element height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've inserted an image before text which acts as either an error or success message. The messages are generated from the back-end and vary, so that effects the height of each paragraph. Below the CSS works with a single line message, but as soon as the message uses 2 or more lines, the image doesn't align vertically and the lines become horizontally uneven.

What's the best way to insert an image before the text and it aligns in relation to the height of the paragraph? I'm using Bootstrap v4 (if that helps

```css
#alertBox , #successBox { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
#alertBox p:before {
 content: url(../images/info.png);
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#successBox p:before {
 content: url(../images/info.png);
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div id="alertBox"></div>
  <div id="successBox"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/media-object/ has a centre aligned media object.

Comment: Would this work inserting the image through `content: url(images/img.jpg)` ?